# Why is the first api.add_files not being included?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following:

**scribe/package.js:**

```
Package.describe({
  summary: 'A rich text editor framework for the web platform http://guardian.github.io/scribe/'
});

Package.on_use(function(api) {
  api.add_files('require.js', 'client');
  api.add_files('scribe.js', 'client');
});
```

For some reason I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

Because `require.js` doesn't show up in the rendered page. Why is that?

File tree:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export all the top global variables from the package. Add this line before the `api.add_files`call:

```
api.export('define')
```

Add a similar line for every global variable you'd like to be abke to use outside of the package.